# Pig Latin converter in Python

Tags: python, performance, pig-latin

How is it and can it be optimised?

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence you want to convert to pig latin: ")

sentence = sentence.split()
for i in range(len(sentence)):
    if sentence[i][0] in "aeiou":
        sentence[i] += 'yay'
    else:
        sentence[i]=sentence[i][1:]+sentence[i][0]
        sentence[i]+='ay'
sentence = ' '.join(sentence)

print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually care about indexes during the iteration; you just want the contents. The loop would be better written as

```
sentence = input(…)
for word in sentence.split():
    if word[0] in "aeiou":
        …
```

How would you reassemble the results?  Noting that each word can be translated independently, I would define a function for that, then use a generator expression.

```
def pig_latin(word):
    if word[0] in "aeiou":
        return word + 'yay'
    else:
        return word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay'

sentence = input("Enter a sentence you want to convert to pig latin: ")
print(' '.join(pig_latin(word) for word in sentence.split()))
```

Comment: you can get rid of `else:` in your `def pig_latin(word)` function, and outdent `return word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay'`